# Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corr

Tags: java, mysql

I am developing a web application with Spring. Since I already have my BDD, I generated my Java classes and now when it compiles I have [this bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvcew.png).

Caused by:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'procedure add column id_procedure varchar(255) not null' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2497) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1540) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2595) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1468) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: post your code as well.

Comment: You have a syntax error, post your query if you want our help

Comment: I have not written code sql javais already my BDD

Comment: CREATE TABLE `procedure` (
  `idProcedure` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dateDebut` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateFin` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `gestionnairedecompte_codeAgent` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `employeur_FHNUM` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: You want to create a table with name ```procedure``` but as stated in the [official page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) it is a reserved keyword.  
If you choose another name for your table it will work.

Comment: Tanks Rabin it’s walk